# Can group by and tidy be used to fit multilevel models (lme) to repeated measures/longitudinal data?

Tags: r, data-manipulation, multi-level, nlme, longitudinal

Consider the following example longitudinal/repeated measures dataset

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
library(nlme)

data <- read.csv("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/study2.csv")
data <- data %>% mutate(dbp =rnorm(120, 30:150), sbp = rnorm(120, 50:200),bmi 
= rnorm(120,15:40), chol = rnorm(120,50:350), insulin = rnorm(120,2:40), educ = rnorm(120,5:10))
```

I can use `group_by %>% do(tidy(*))` to run several unadjusted and adjusted **single-level** regression models (looping through list of outcomes & exposures) and extract model results to the data frame as follows

```
out <-c("pulse","insulin","chol")
exp <- c("factor(exertype)","sbp","dbp")
conf <- c("bmi","factor(diet)")

#Unadjusted models - single level regression (lm)
#################################################
Unadjusted <- expand.grid(out, exp) %>%
group_by(Var1) %>% rowwise() %>%
summarise(frm = paste0(Var1, "~", Var2)) %>%
group_by(model_id = row_number(),frm) %>%
do(tidy(lm(.$frm, data = data))) %>%
mutate(lci = estimate-(1.96*std.error)) %>%
mutate(uci = estimate+(1.96*std.error))

#Adjusted models - single level regression (lm)
###############################################
Adjusted <- expand.grid(out, exp, conf) %>%
group_by(Var1, Var2) %>%
summarise(Var3 = paste0(Var3, collapse = "+")) %>%
rowwise() %>%
summarise(frm = paste0(Var1, "~", Var2, "+", Var3)) %>%
group_by(model_id = row_number(), frm) %>%
do(tidy(lm(.$frm, data = data))) %>%
mutate(lci = estimate-(1.96*std.error)) %>%
mutate(uci = estimate+(1.96*std.error))
```

I would like to use the same process to fit **multilevel** models to account for the repeated data. using the example code:

```
lme(sbp ~ pulse+factor(diet)+time, data=data, random= ~time|id, method ="ML")
```

HOWEVER, when I try to do this, e.g. using:

```
#Unadjusted models - multi-level regression (lme)
#################################################
Unadjusted <- expand.grid(out, exp) %>%
group_by(Var1) %>% rowwise() %>%
summarise(frm = paste0(Var1, "~", Var2)) %>%
group_by(model_id = row_number(),frm) %>%
do(tidy(lme(.$frm, data = data, random= ~time|id, method = "ML"))) %>%
mutate(lci = estimate-(1.96*std.error)) %>%
mutate(uci = estimate+(1.96*std.error))
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error in UseMethod("lme") : no applicable method for 'lme' applied to an object of class "character"
```

Any ideas on how to get this working for lme type models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike `lm`, `lme` will not accept a formula as a character value. You need to explicitly cast it to a formula. Try just adding `as.formula()`

```
do(tidy(lme(as.formula(.$frm), ...))) %>%
```

Comment: Thanks, using as.formula gets it to run but the output looks strange/incorrect - It gives results for different levels rather than overall, PLUS it doesn't include SE to derive confidence intervals??

Comment: Can you run these models with `lme` directly? Does it give the results you want? You didn't include the desired result. I can only get rid of the error you listed.

Comment: I have figured out the problem - i needed to specify 'effects = "fixed"' when calling the tidy dataframe. Thanks